# How to publish amqp message using the default amqp exchange with Mule 4

Tags: mule, exchange-server, publish, mulesoft

Using Mule 4 , im trying to publish a message to the default amqp exchange but i still got

`description=Exchange was not found.
detailedDescription=Exchange was not found.
errorType=AMQP:EXCHANGE_NOT_FOUND`

this is my XML code :

```
<amqp:publish doc:name="Publish" doc:id="7282ee0e-9188-4a8a-a1f7-eefe5b98ce40" 
config-ref="AMQP_Config" exchangeName="#['']">
<amqp:routing-keys >
   <amqp:routing-key value="Test" />
</amqp:routing-keys>
<amqp:message>
  <amqp:properties/>
</amqp:message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating a new exchange "testExchange", referring to the documentation provided here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/migration-connectors-amqp

Using the default with rabbitMQ, the default name is 'amq.default'.

Comment: I don't want to create a new exchange i want to use the default amqp exchange